# spark sql - converting date from MMM dd, yyyy to yy-MMM-dd

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have date coming as `string` in format `MMM dd, yyyy` and I want to convert that into `yy-MMM-dd` format

i.e. `Jan 14, 2018` should be converted to `18-JAN-14`

**following code convert it into `yyyy-mm-dd` formta**

```
select to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp("Jan 14, 2018","MMM dd, yyyy"))) as date
```

**however, following code returns null**

```
select to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp("Jan 14, 2018","MMM dd, yyyy")), "yy-MMM-dd") as date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_format` to convert from date to string:

```
> spark.sql("""select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp("Jan 14, 2018","MMM dd, yyyy")), "yy-MMM-dd") as date""").show
+---------+
|     date|
+---------+
|18-Jan-14|
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hive, `to_date` doesn't accept a format argument. The required format should be an argument to `from_unixtime`.

```
to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp("Jan 14, 2018","MMM dd, yyyy"), "yy-MMM-dd"))
```

Note that `to_date` conversion would only be required prior to Hive version 2.1.0, to convert the `string` return type, as the later versions return a `date` type.